# how to stream audio from server to an android app

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I own a website with bunch of mp3 files - [here](http://www.kolotoc.sk)

I would like to create a radio (audio stream) on the server and an android app that will play the stream on many android devices.

Can anyone help me with the architecture (server side and android side)? Are there any ready-made open source solutions that can facilitate the development/implementation?

my website runs on the LAMP stack (Debian)

I would like the users of the android app to be able to influence the playlist - I would like to display about 3-5 randomly chosen songs in the android app and give the app users the ability to vote which song out of those 3-5 random ones will play next (poll/voting)

Answer (score 0):

You require two things:
i) Streaming server which is not difficult to search.
ii) Player at Android app capable of playing Streaming audio and/or video if applicable.

VideoLAN (VLC) player is most used for this purpose. You can import their SDK and use as per your requirement.

See [VLC Git](https://wiki.videolan.org/git) wiki page for SDK information.